# SSH Permission denied (publickey) - fail at preauth step

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, putty, ssh-keys

i tired different solution found internet to resolve that issue with no luck:

- Correct permissions for keys at `/etc/ssh/`, 400 for private rsa key and 600 for public rsa key.
- 700 for `/home/usersrv/.ssh/` folder. `authorized_keys` does not existed. I created it later with permission 600; file still empty, do I supposed to copy something inside? Home directory is on the same volume with system.
- Tried with different ports: 22 and 2222

Server configuration `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`uncommented part:

```
Port 2222
AddressFamily any
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
ListenAddress ::

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key 

PermitRootLogin no  

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no  

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no   

KerberosAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication no 
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
X11UseLocalhost yes
PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
```

When i try to connect from Win+PuTTy, i have error message:No supported authentication methods available (server sent public key)

```
    /etc/ssh/sshd_config line 37: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_7.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:F61cGX7XOyKpBMChyVtxyaH2T23NoIr9+iAKCjRAbO4
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 22.
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from 192.168.1.98 port 40922 on 192.168.1.98 port 22
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u3
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 110/65534 [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512 [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user usersrv service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
reprocess config line 37: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
debug1: PAM: initializing for "usersrv"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "192.168.1.98"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
Connection closed by 192.168.1.98 port 40922 [preauth]
debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: PAM: cleanup
debug1: Killing privsep child 941
debug1: audit_event: unhandled event 12
```

And then i try to login locally (directly under usersrv)m i got an error: Permission denied (publickey).

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 37: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_7.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:F61cGX7XOyKpBMChyVtxyaH2T23NoIr9+iAKCjRAbO4
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug1: Bind to port 2222 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 2222.
debug1: Bind to port 2222 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 2222.
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from 192.168.1.98 port 54596 on 192.168.1.98 port 2222
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u3
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 110/65534 [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512 [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user usersrv service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
reprocess config line 37: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
debug1: PAM: initializing for "usersrv"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "192.168.1.98"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
Connection closed by 192.168.1.98 port 54596 [preauth]
debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: PAM: cleanup
debug1: Killing privsep child 1111
debug1: audit_event: unhandled event 12
```

Anyone had the same issue or know a solution?
Kind regards.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you didn't add public key of your computer to your server. Public keys from client computers are stored in **authorized_keys** file.

Change this line in /etc/ssh/sshd_config to yes (later you can turn it back again)

`PasswordAuthentication yes`

And restart ssh demon

`sudo service ssh restart`

Then issue the following command from your client computer to export public key to the server:

`ssh-copy-id usersrv@server`

In the command prompt enter your password. After that you will gain access to your server via ssh-keys.

Comment: The user needs to disable password authentication once this is done. Password authentication should not be left enabled on an internet accessible SSH server.

Comment: this actually works.